# Plotting with Octave 5.1.0 results in interrupted lines

Tags: plot, octave

Plotting curves or lines with Octave 5.1.0 sometimes, in the figure,  the curves or the lines are interrupted.

My system is UBUNTU 18_04.
To install Octave 5.1.0 I followed the indication reported [in this link](https://www.math.univ-paris13.fr/~cuvelier/Octave/Ubuntu_18-04LTS.html#x37-75000.9.1).

I tried to change the `graphics_toolkit` (there are 3 possibility 'qt', 'gnuplot' and 'fltk'), but changing sometimes solves the problem and sometime doesn't.

```matlab
#!/usr/bin/octave -qf

D2R = pi/180.;

ang_d=0:1:360;
ang_r=ang_d*D2R;

h=figure;

plot(ang_d, sin(ang_r));

refresh;

waitfor(h)
```

In the picture, the curve is interrupted.

Comment: Thank you Cris for re-formatting the message. I can also add that installing the same version of Octave on Windiws 10, the plot is correct.

Comment: I cannot reproduce on my machine. Does this script work as intended if you run it from within octave? (as opposed to from the linux terminal, which is what it appears you're doing given the shebang syntax)

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of the plot?

Comment: @Andy (I'm guessing he doesn't have enough rep for that)

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I tried the test of Tasos and the picture is always interrupted. I'm unable to post a screenshot. I followed a guide that say push PRTSC/SCRN; gnome save in the dir Picture the image then CTRL+G on the post but does not put the image in the post. Sorry

Comment: can you try posting the image on an image uploading site (like imgur) and share the link in the comments?

Comment: This is a link to the screenshot https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img921/6600/oCseaa.png

Comment: There are any news?

Comment: Now also me I can write <<I'm guessing you do not  have enough rep for that>>